# How to determine if a 2nd service was done within 2 min of the other?

Tags: sas

How to determine if a 2nd service was done within 2 min of the other?

Hi team I'm working on 2 tables an I need to determine if table1  service A was done within 2 min of table2  service B.

And also  to determine how many  service B  did not have any service A here is example below!

```
TABLE 1
ID.    Ser    Start.  End                
Qw.    A     23May2016:00:34:00.     23May2016:00:40:00

TABLE 2
ID.    Ser    Start.  End               
Qw.   B    23May2016:00:35:00.     23May2016:00:41:00
```

In the example table One open within 2 min of the 2nd service I would want to see table two in a dataset

That's first part  here is 2nd part

```
TABLE 1
ID.    Ser    Start.    End            
Qw.    A     26May2016:00:29:00.     26May2016:00:40:00

TABLE 2
ID.    Ser    Start.     End                                  
Qw.    A     26May2016:00:38:00.     26May2016:00:40:00
```

On this example what it's showing is there was a service B but no service A open up within 2 min I would want that on its own **dataset** .... thanks again  for help. Anyone?

Comment: Are there multiple observations with each ID in each table?

Comment: Yes there can be more than one it's a one day pull

Comment: Can you post example datasets that reflect the data you're working with then? One observation isn't really helpful

Comment: Some things remain unclear to me... Please clarify what are your input datasets, and what would be your output dataset(s). Also, from what columns should the time difference be calculated? I'd guess `Start` from both tables, but it's not entirely clear. And finally, as @superfluous said, please add rows to your example, adding in rows having same `ID`'s (in both tables if that is what your real datasets have) and specify how to handle them. Then I'll be glad to help.

Comment: Table1 is service A  and Table 2 is service B.    I want to to know all the service B that had a service A open within 2 min .... the way I determine that is I use the start time from table a and start time from table B  I have been kicking idea of merge tables to one an doing inner join  that have a.id = b.id a.date= b.date  a.start > b.start something to that effect ...thank you f or assistance much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution. I've added rows so we can see what happens in all possible situations.

```
data TABLE1;
  informat id $3. Ser $1. Start datetime19. End datetime19.;
  format Start End datetime19.;
  input id Ser Start End;
  datalines;
Qa. A 23May2016:00:34:00 23May2016:00:40:00
Qw. A 23May2016:00:34:00 23May2016:00:40:00
Qz. A 23May2016:00:34:00 23May2016:00:40:00
;

data TABLE2;
  informat id $3. Ser $1. Start datetime19. End datetime19.;
  format Start End datetime19.;
  input id Ser Start End;
  datalines;
Qw. B 23May2016:00:35:00 23May2016:00:41:00
Qz. A 23May2016:00:37:00 23May2016:00:42:00
;

proc sort data = Table1;
  by id;
run;

proc sort data = Table2;
  by id;
run;

data want;
  merge TABLE1(IN = T1 RENAME = (Start=StartA End=EndA))
        TABLE2(IN = T2 RENAME = (Start=StartB End=EndB));
  by id;
  if t1 and t2 then do;
    if intck("seconds",StartA, StartB) <= 120 then in_time = 1;
    else in_time = 0;
  end;
  else if t1 and not t2 then in_time = -1;
run;
```

### Results

Column `in_time` takes value 0 for "No", 1 for "Yes", and -1 for "No corresponding entry in table2".

[image]